# Warning: msql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySql-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to programming and following online tutorial.

I got an error please help.

Connected successfully

Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/www/divitiae.net.co/make_my_tables.php on line 22

below is line 22

```
include_once("php_includes/db_connect.php");

$query = mysql_query($db_connect, $tbl_users);
if ($query === TRUE) {
echo "<h3>user table created OK :) </h3>"; 
} else {
echo "<h3>user table NOT created :( </h3>";
```

}

Comment: Have you tried look for [mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL Link](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+mysql_query%28%29%3A+supplied+argument+is+not+a+valid+MySQL+Link)? Al those answers say about the same thing.

Comment: what is in `$tbl_users` ?

Comment: (BTW: your arguments seem to be in the wrong order)

Comment: Please note: The `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated. You should avoid using them. Consider using either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead.

Comment: No no no no. Please do not use **mysql_**. First of all, you're using it terribly wrong, and it's extremely outdated and unsafe. Before you do any harm to yourself, quit that tutorial, and find a good PDO tutorial, here's a quick and dirty http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that the `$db_connect` variable you are passing to the `mysql_query` function is not a MySQL connection object, as would be returned by the `mysql_connect` function.

Your `php_includes/db_connect.php` should contain something like:

```
$db_connect = mysql_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('databasename');
```

This will connect to the database on server `hostname` using the `username` and `password` provided. It then selects the database `databasename` as the database to perform operations on.

**Warning!**

You really, really, *REALLY* should not use the `mysql_*` set of functions because they are deprecated and you should use either the `mysqli_*` functions or implement `PDO`, as those are more flexible, safer, supported, and have better features.

Comment: I corrected the msql to msqli and corrected the php_includes but still getting the same error.

Comment: @user2666000 Make sure that your `hostname` is set to the hostname of your database server, that `username` and `password` are correct for your database, that `databasename` is the name of the database you have access to. You also need to make sure that you have access to the database and database server.